# Admin-Ajax is slowing down my Wordpress site

Tags: css, ajax, wordpress, admin-ajax

I am running a Wordpress website: [link](https://wintersportvakantie.nl/land/ijsland/)

All plugins, wordpress and theme are updated to the latest version.

I am also running on Woocommerce. When disabling the Woocommerce-plugin, the site is running fast. When enabling Woocommerce, site is slowing down desperately.

Theme is also compatible with Woocommerce according to the theme-developer. However, the developer can't figure out what the issue is.

I already installed WP-Rocket plugin to optimize speed and caching the site, without result.

When checking Pingdom Tools and GTMetrix, the waterfall shows a huge slowdown in: admin-ajax.php?action=grandtour_custom_css

See testing results here: [link](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/wintersportvakantie.nl/abgBKYI7)

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I checked your website speed test o Gtmatrix under waterfall.
One of your ajax action is taking 3.7 seconds, which actually is main reason of delay.

You should remove this ajax action.

```
remove_action('grandtour_custom_css');
```

Check wordpress documentation for remove action. [Wordpress Documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action)

remove_action() must be called inside function as shown below.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_my_action' );
function remove_my_action(){

   remove_action( 'grandtour_custom_css');
   remove_action( 'wp_ajax_grandtour_custom_css');
   remove_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_grandtour_custom_css');

}
```

On next step add css from ajax call [here](https://wintersportvakantie.nl/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=grandtour_custom_css) on wordpress customizer under appreance.

If it still does not solve your problem then try to optimize the animation css.

Comment: Thanks so far! Stupid question maybe, but where do I put this piece of code?

Comment: You should place below code inside functions.php file at theme root. remember to find wp_head action there, place below code inside acton call back function. remove_action( 'grandtour_custom_css');

Comment: This is my code. I don't know where to put it. Im so sorry for being an amature

Comment: `add_action('wp_ajax_grandtour_custom_css', 'grandtour_custom_css');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_grandtour_custom_css', 'grandtour_custom_css');

function grandtour_custom_css() {



 get_template_part("/modules/custom_css");

 die();
}

/**
* Setup responsive CSS function
**/
add_action('wp_ajax_grandtour_responsive_css', 'grandtour_responsive_css');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_grandtour_responsive_css', 'grandtour_responsive_css');

function grandtour_responsive_css() {
 get_template_part("/modules/responsive_css");

 die();
}`

Comment: comment these two lines. //add_action('wp_ajax_grandtour_custom_css', 'grandtour_custom_css'); //add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_grandtour_custom_css', 'grandtour_custom_css');

Comment: I am so sorry, that I don't understand you. Can you maybe help me out how to adjust this code? <br/>`add_action('wp_ajax_grandtour_custom_css', 'grandtour_custom_css'); 
 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_grandtour_custom_css', 'grandtour_custom_css');


function grandtour_custom_css() {

 get_template_part("/modules/custom_css");

 die();
}`

Comment: remove this code get_template_part("/modules/custom_css"); die(); from function grandtour_custom_css() {  }

Comment: Then copy css from from following file to Appreance -> customise -> Additional Css https://wintersportvakantie.nl/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=grandtour_custom_css

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I removed that line AND I added the content of that file to the additional CSS, but without any luck :(

Comment: I still see ajax call is returning the animation css. add remove actions inside wordpress head action as mentioned in answer above.